# Mysql query not returning correct value when date field in where condition

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

In my `sales` table the `sale_date` field is in `date` format

When I run the query,

```
SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE sale_date=2014-10-01;
```

Return no result. Actually the `sale_date` field contains the value **2014-10-01**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without the quotes, this is interpreted as three integers with the subtraction operator (`-`) between them: `2014 - 10 - 01 = 2003`. You need to express this value as a `date`, e.g., with the [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `sales` 
WHERE  sale_date = STR_TO_DATE('2014-10-01', '%m-%d-%Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes for date.

you can write simply as follow.

`SELECT * FROM`sales`WHERE sale_date='2014-10-01';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE sale_date between "2014-10-01 00:00:00" and "2014-10-01 23:59:59";
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE date(sale_date) = "2014-10-01";
```

If records are very large, then 2nd query will take time to respond than first.